# Hide back button in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using statefull and stateless widget for some of screens in flutter.

I want to hide back button is some screen and wanted to display back button is some screen how can i do it.
I had not written any code for back button it just appear by default.

I am using below code to push to another screen with parameter

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Nextscreen('parameter1','Parameter2'),
          ));
```

or below code when there is no parameter :
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(NEXT_SCREEN);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to hide the back button in the AppBar of your Scaffold page pass AppBar the property `automaticallyImplyLeading` with a value of `false`:

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    ...
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

In the screen where you make the `Scaffold`, you can pass something to the `leading` property of the `AppBar` and it will override the default back button widget appearing. So if you wanted nothing there, you could just pass an empty `Container` when your parameter is present and `null` otherwise:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: widget.parameter1 ?? Container() : null,
    ...
  ),
  ...
),
```